# access variable from string name

Tags: php, arrays, string, variables

I have this variable

```
$foo['title'] = 'Hello World';
```

I want to access this variable from a string.

```
$string = '$foo["title"]';
```

How can I *display "Hello World" by my variable `$string`*?

I searched an other topic, i found something similar, unfortunately it doesn't work.

```
$foo['title'] = "Hello, world!";
$bar = "foo['title']";
echo $$bar;
```

Comment: Why can't you just do `$bar = $foo['title'];`?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I am not sure I understand you goal.

Do you want maybe this?

```
$foo['title'] = "Hello, world!";
$bar = "$foo[title]";
echo $bar;
```

The result:

> Hello, world!

This is the same as this:

```
$bar = $foo['title'];
```

Or you would like to prepend/append something? Like this:

```
$bar = 'prepend something ' . $foo['title'] . ' append something';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the argument to the array away from the variable name, and then enclose the variable name in curly braces. So:

```
// get array argument
$matches = array();
preg_match("/\['(?s)(.*)'\]/", $bar, $matches);
$array_arg = $matches[1];

// get variable name
$arr = explode("[", $string, 2);
$var_name = $arr[0];

// put it together
${$var_name}[$array_arg]
```